# Chrome web socket is not getting connected, throwing Web Socket Error

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome, websocket

I am using socket.io to connect to a socket server, which is also created using the socket.io library. I am using the WSS to connect, but in the Chrome I am getting this Web Socket Error.
`

```
error:=>  Error: websocket error
    at Bt.onError (506.c7b969e0906175d3.js:1:34490)
    at ws.onerror [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror] (506.c7b969e0906175d3.js:1:38923)
    at WebSocket.We (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:11499)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:7187)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.e9380cad7172dc30.js:1:379680)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:7108)
    at M.runTask (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:2582)
    at m.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:8238)
    at Z (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:20801)
    at N (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:21094)
```

`
But in the Firefox the connection established and it is working fine.
I am using the following technology stack.
Node JS (Socket io) for socket server
Angular 14 (Socket io client) for frontend.

I have tried to connect using the socket io client with the following code snippet.
`

```
this.socket = io(environment.SOCKET_URL + "admin", 
{
          
transports: ['websocket'],
          
autoConnect: true,
          
reconnection: true,
          
upgrade: true
      
});
      
this.socket.connect();
```

But in the angular side I am getting the following error on the Google Chrome.

`

```
error:=>  Error: websocket error
    at Bt.onError (506.c7b969e0906175d3.js:1:34490)
    at ws.onerror [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror] (506.c7b969e0906175d3.js:1:38923)
    at WebSocket.We (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:11499)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:7187)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.e9380cad7172dc30.js:1:379680)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:7108)
    at M.runTask (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:2582)
    at m.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:8238)
    at Z (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:20801)
    at N (polyfills.8e48777d543643e2.js:1:21094)
```

`